# scanForPeripherals(withServices: ) doesn't return anything if I provide the CBUUID value

Tags: ios, swift, ios-bluetooth

I am trying to discover only 1 bluetooth device with a certain identification. I can see on my phone that the bluetooth id is `"64107B7B-E8C0-1F13-C665-72BD638C1609"`, but when I put that value in the function `.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "64107B7B-E8C0-1F13-C665-72BD638C1609")])` my phone doesn't discover any devices for some reason.

If I run this function as `.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)`, then the device will be found and when I print out the peripheral found this is what I get:

```
Peripheral Discovered: <CBPeripheral: 0x839238, identifier = 64107B7B-E8C0-1F13-C665-72BD638C1609, name = DSD TECH, mtu = 0, state = disconnected>
```

So as you can see the identifier is the same id that I am searching for, but for some reason the bluetooth device doesn't show up when I specify the ID I want to search for. Any suggestions on why my bluetooth device isn't showing up when I specify an ID to search for?

Here is my function I am running when I don't receive any values back:

```
func startScanning() {
    let kBLE = "64107B7B-E8C0-1F13-C665-72BD638C1609"
    let BLE = CBUUID(string: kBLE)
    centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BLE])
}
```

Comment: That's the UUID of the device, not the UUID of a service that the device is advertising.

Comment: See the doc of the method: `You can provide an array of CBUUID objects — representing service UUIDs — in the serviceUUIDs parameter. When you do, the central manager returns only peripherals that advertise the services you specify.`

Comment: Yep you're right I figured it out. Thanks @Larme

Comment: @Larme your comment provides the correct and useful advice.  So thanks, but also you should submit it as a legit answer a get proper credit.